# How to give a button both a background color and a hover color?

Tags: python, pyside6, pyqt6

I want my button to have a blue background, then a green background when you hover the mouse over it.

This is my code:

```
self.button.setStyleSheet("background-color:blue")
self.button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton::hover"
                          "{"
                          "background-color:green;"
                          "}")
```

How can I make these two lines work at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just join the qt stylesheets:

```py
self.button.setStyleSheet(
    """
    QPushButton{
        background-color:blue;
    }
    QPushButton::hover{
        background-color:green;
    }
    """
)
```