# PushButton Color Change By Mouse move

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

I want to have a push button in Qt C++ which changes color while hovered.

I have tried creating a custom class from QPushButton and overriding `enterEvent` and `leaveEvent` methods as below, but it didn't have an effect on the color.

```cpp
class ColorChangingButtom : public QPushButton{
public:
    ColorChangingButtom(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QPushButton(parent){
        setStyleSheet("QPushButtom {background-color:blue; color white;}");
    }
protected:
    void enterEvent(QMouseEvent *event)  {
        QPushButton::mouseMoveEvent(event);
        setStyleSheet("QPushButtom {background-color:red; color white;}");
    }
    void leaveEvent(QEvent *event) override{
        QPushButton::leaveEvent(event);
        setStyleSheet("QPushButtom {background-color:blue; color white;}");
    }
};
```

Comment: You might need to call [setMouseTracking(true)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop).  Also note that you should call `QPushButton::enterEvent` from within your `enterEvent` override -- *not* `QPushButton::mouseMoveEvent`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to give a button both a background color and a hover color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71696850/how-to-give-a-button-both-a-background-color-and-a-hover-color)

Comment: There is no need for subclassing, just use proper [selector types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) along with the `:hover` rule to apply color changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Hover and Pressed stylesheet Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161119/using-hover-and-pressed-stylesheet-qt)